# Grid Drag & Drop: Suppress for some records (groups)

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4

Hy there,

is it possible to control which records can be dragged and where they can be dropped (suppress drag-operation either right from the beginning or in the middle during hovering)?

What i need in detail is the following:

I'm having a grid with some groups (lets say male & female) and only want to activate the d&d inside group 'female' which means 2 things:

1.) I started dragging a record from group 'female' (Lisa). As soon as the drag is outside the group 'female' (above group 'male'...) it should display an error-state like when dragging outside the bounds of the grid:
[image: Example of the error-state]

2.) Starting to drag an item from group 'male' should either not be possible at all (just don't show the d&d panel) or show the error-state like mentioned above right from the beginning and never change to "correct"-state.

Thanks,

mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around in the sources of ext i just found a solution which works but isn't perfect at all:

The "drop-allowed-indication" can be handled by the underlying DropZone which is created in onViewRender of the treeviewdragdrop-plugin. This is not documented but can be seen in [the source-code](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/source/TreeViewDragDrop.html#Ext-tree-plugin-TreeViewDragDrop) of the plugin.

Everything that needs to be done (at least for this example) is to override/extend the onNodeOver- & onContainerOver-method of the DropZone to return the appropriate css-class for the drop-not-allowed- or drop-allowed-indication.

```
Ext.override(Ext.view.DropZone, {
    onNodeOver: function(nodeData, source, e, data) {
        if (data && data.records && data.records[0]) {
            // The check should be better specified, e.g. a
            // female with the name 'Malena' would be recognized as male!
            if (nodeData.innerHTML.indexOf(data.records[0].get('sex')) < 0) {
                return this.dropNotAllowed;
            }
        }
        return this.callOverridden([nodeData, source, e, data]);
    },
    onContainerOver: function(source, e, data) {
        return this.dropNotAllowed;
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/suamikim/auXdQ/

#### There are a few things i don't like about this solution:

1. The override changes (per definition...) the behaviour of all DropZones in my application. How can i only override/extend the specific DropZone of one grid?
   I've tried the following:

   - Add an interceptor to the dropZone after the gridview has been rendered: http://jsfiddle.net/suamikim/uv8tX/
     At first this seems to work because it shows the correct drop-allowed-indication but it drops the record even if the indicator shows that it's not allowed (it always shows the "green line"...)
   - Define a new dnd-plugin which extends the treeviewdragdrop-plugin and just override the onNodeOver-method of the dropZone after it's creation: http://jsfiddle.net/suamikim/5v67W/
     This kind of does the opposite from the interception-method. It also shows the correct indication but it never shows the "green line" and won't allow the drop anywhere...
2. The class i'm overriding (Ext.view.DropZone) is marked private in [the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.ViewDropZone) with a note that it shouldn't be used directly...

I would really appreciate some comments on those 2 issues and maybe even some better solutions!

Thanks, mik

---

Edit:
I adjusted the version in which i defined a new dnd-plugin which extended the original gridviewdragdrop-plugin. The "magic" was to also extend gridviewdropzone and extend the onNodeOver-method instead of just overriding it.
This needs to be done because the original onNodeOver-method which is now called by callParent handles the "green line" and finally allows the drop.
The only thing my extended gridviewdragdrop-plugin does now is to create a instance of the new dropzone-class instead of the standard gridviewdropzone in the onViewRender-method.
This seems like a reasonable way so far:

```
// Extend the treeview dropzone
Ext.define('ExtendedGridViewDropZone', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.ViewDropZone',

    onNodeOver: function(nodeData, source, e, data) {
        if (data && data.records && data.records[0]) {
            // The check should be specified, e.g. a female with the name 'Malena' would be recognized as male!
            if (nodeData.innerHTML.indexOf(data.records[0].get('sex')) < 0) {
                    return this.dropNotAllowed;
            }
        }

        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    onContainerOver: function(source, e, data) {
        return this.dropNotAllowed;
    }
});

Ext.define('ExtendedGridDnD', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop',
    alias: 'plugin.extendeddnd',

    onViewRender: function(view) {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        // Create a instance of ExtendedGridViewDropZone instead of Ext.grid.ViewDropZone
        this.dropZone = Ext.create('ExtendedGridViewDropZone', {
            view: view,
            ddGroup: this.dropGroup || this.ddGroup
        });
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5v67W/1/

Nonetheless I'd still appreciate different approaches because it still feels like it could be done easier...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this for Ext 5 and 6

On your treepanel definition:

```
 listeners: {        
        viewready           : 'onViewReady'
    }
```

on your ViewController:

```
onViewReady       : function (tree) {
    var view = tree.getView(),
        dd = view.findPlugin('treeviewdragdrop'),
        rec;

    dd.dropZone.onNodeOver = function (data, e) {
        rec = view.getRecord(e.getTarget(view.itemSelector));
        return rec.get('customProperty') === 'someValue' ? this.dropAllowed : this.dropNotAllowed;
    }
},
```

reference https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282685
          https://www.sencha.com/blog/declarative-listeners-in-ext-js-5/